# httpd.conf mod_rewrite HTTPS and remove PHP extension

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, https, httpd.conf

I have been stuck on this for ages.
I can't seem to get httpd.conf to rewrite URLs to add https (if it is not being used) and remove the .php extension.
I can get either to work but not both at the same time. https://example.com/index gives a 404 error when index.php exists.

So what I am trying to do is turn URLs such as example.com/index.php into https://example.com/index

If I turn off the force HTTPS rule, it works.
httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php  [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule $ https://example.com/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

I have added multiple rules such as:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

And:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

But to no avail.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working as expected.

For your `http` block

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ – [F]
```

For your `https` (ssl) block

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl
RewriteRule ^ – [F]
```

Note: i suggest you to use a htaccess in root folder (ssl document root folder must be the same as "http" domain). This way, you won't have split/duplicate code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I still get the same behaviour. If I remove the first rule (for https) and then use http it works. 404 if https.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. You can see my edited answer about it